# jquery each function and drag and drop jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

why when i drag and drop 2 "Android" there are 3 "i want one li for each android inside #dz" inside #docs ? and 6 when i drop 3 etc...

```
    $("#dz").droppable({
        accept: ".systeme",
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($("#dz"));
            setTimeout(function(){

                $("#dz .android").each(function() {
                    $("#docs").append("<li>i want one li for each android inside #dz</li>");
                }, 10);
              });
        }
```

https://codepen.io/Cyril29/pen/dybLaam

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becouse you **add** *"i want one li for each android inside #dz"*

When u already have 1 "Android" in `#dz` already 1 *"i want one li for each android inside #dz"*

When u drop second "Android" `$("#dz .android").each()` calling 2 times (in 1 already **adding** 2 new)

Solution 1:

```
drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($("#dz"));
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#docs").empty() // remove all elements in #docs 
        $("#dz .android").each(function() {
          $("#docs").append("<li>i want one li for each android inside #dz</li>");
        }, 10);
      });
    }
```

Solution 2:

```
drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($("#dz"));
      setTimeout(function(){
          $("#docs").append("<li>i want one li for each android inside #dz</li>");
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using the [$each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to loop through `$("#dz .android")`.

One `li` element appears first because there is only one `.android` to loop over.

On the second attempt, the first `li` **still exists** and you are have dragged another over. Two now exist within `$("#dz .android")`.

So, the each loop fires twice which creates two more `li`s. Thus, there are now 3 list elements.

On the third draggable event, 3 `li`s are created which are added to the existing 3. Hence 6 in total.